# Help wiring a ceiling fan switch with oscillating and fan switch

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, fans, motion-sensor

Here is what I have going on. I currently have a motion sensing switch wired in the garage to a single light. From that light two outlets have been added to plug in two additional overhead shop lights.  I have ran 14-3 wire from the switch box up to where the light was. The light has been replaced by an oscillating ceiling fan. I would like to keep the motion sensing switch to control the two overhead shop lights and wire the fan switch separate from the shop lights to just control the fan.  The motion sensing switch has just one red screw and one black screw. The switch for the oscillating fan has one blue wire, one white/black wire, one black wire and one white wire. There are 3 sets of wires coming into the box now 4 with the 14-3 I ran.  can you please help me wire this?

Comment: Can you give us a quick diagram of what you have and what you want?

Comment: You need to post the brand and model of your switch or a link to the manual. There is not much of a standard for motion sensing switches. The white/black seems out of place since you would normally only need three wires to switch a light on and off from the sensor.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box for that matter?